# How 25 donuts can be distributed to 4 police officers so that each officer gets at least 3 but no more than 7 donuts using Generating Functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Good evening, I'm trying to solve this counting problem using generating functions, however, I don't know what to after I get to this point, I've seen in a couple of videos that I have to use something called **convulution**, moreover, I don't know how to do it.

$$[x^{25}]g(x)=[x^{25}](x^3+x^4+...+x^7)^4$$
$$=[x^{25}]x^{12}(x^0+x^1+...+x^4)^4$$
$$=[x^{13}](\frac{1-x^5}{1-x})^4$$
$$=[x^{13}](1-x^5)^4(1-x)^{-4}$$
I'll really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Why police officers and doughnuts ? I must not have the same sense of humor as your instructor.

Comment: It's an exercise from a textbook ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Taylor's Series expansion at $x=0$ or the negative binomial theorem to expand the second part of the product, thus

$(1-\binom41 x^5 + \binom42 x^{10}...)(1+\binom41 x + \binom52 x^2 +\binom63x^3 +...  +\binom{16}{13} x^{13})$

and collect the coefficients of the $x^{13}$ terms in the product.

This would work out to

$1\cdot\binom{16}{13} -\binom41\cdot\binom{11}8 +\binom42\cdot\binom63 = 20$